# Service for scheduling sending of emails

Tags: email

I'm looking for something out of the box to programmatically send emails at a given point in the future. Something like Amazon SES, but that also takes care of the temporal aspect. If SES just had a date/time-parameter for when to send the email, the problem would be solved.

Does anyone know of some service, API, lib or open-source project that does this? The less I have to do myself, the better. Preferably it should be http-based.

I understand how to build something like this myself, that's not the issue. I would simply prefer to pay for it rather than maintain yet another custom-built service.

Answer (score 0):

Had a look around http://sendible.com/ have an API for doing this using REST/HTTP.

Looking at their pricing and what they offer it maybe overkill depending on your needs....

Here are the links I found, the code example shows scheduling an email message.

http://code.google.com/p/sendible-api/wiki/CreateMessage

http://sendible.com/features/social-media-dashboard

Also...

http://mailchimp.com/ have email campaigns that can be scheduled, but have no support for single emails as far as I can tell - they use Amazon SES for sending.

Comment: Looks like Sendible can do the job, best suggestion so far. Something more "pure" would be cool though; they offer a lot of extra cheese I don't need. Tack iaf James ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that Mandrill (MailChimp's transactional e-mail service) has this feature:

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/24331201-Can-I-schedule-a-message-to-send-at-a-specific-time-

Answer (score 0):

You may check [huhumails.com](https://www.huhumails.com)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the website.

[HuhuMails](https://www.huhumails.com) is a scheduler program for Amazon SES. It also takes care of the rate limit and make sure you don't exceed your per-second limit. And it also accepts date and timezone parameters if you want to send your email in the future.

I was looking for an email scheduler, and I couldn't find anything on the market that's simple and according to what I need. That's why I created the service. I'm currently using it on my other production websites. Hopefully, others will find it useful as well.